# Is authenticated encryption unnecessary if the message is digitally signed?

Tags: signature, authentication, authenticated-encryption

Normally, it is necessary to use authenticated encryption if the message may be tampered with.  Can the authentecation be omitted if the message has been otherwise authenticated?

Comment: Do you still want confidentiality? ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer bad wording; edited

Comment: See my comment to Richie's answer. ​ ​

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, message authentication can be omitted when using an appropriate digital signature on the ciphertext.

A digital signature hashes the message, then encrypts the hash with a nonce and asymmetric key, which makes the security similar to HMAC.

The reason authenticated encryption is preferred is that it is generally less computationally expensive than a digital signature, and easier to build a MAC construct that is side channel resistant.

Comment: Message "authentication can be omitted ... appropriate digital signature" _on the ciphertext_. ​ When it's on the plaintext, the result can be malleable for certain encryption schemes. ​ Also, digital signatures [are not encryptions](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/68836/49075); see [this question](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/14875/991). ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer In what way would they be malleable?

Comment: @RickyDemer I made the assumption it was on ciphertext, as he was asking about authenticated encryption with authentication omitted, I will edit to make that crystal clear

Comment: @kasperd : ​ ​ ​ For plaintext-ciphertext pairs ​ [p0,c0],[p1,c1],...,[pn,cn] , ​ the adversary can compose a ciphertext c such that which of p0,p1,...,pn,$\bot$ c decrypts to depends detectably on more of what the plaintexts were than just their lengths. ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer Are you assuming that the adversary is giving access to an unencrypted signature on the plaintext? Sending $S(m)||E(m)$ is clearly flawed. But I would expect $S(E(m))||E(m)$ and $E(S(m)||m)$ to both be equally secure.

Comment: @kasperd : ​ ​ ​ No. ​ If there are IND-CPA encryption schemes, then there are are IND-CPA encryption schemes for which the E(S(m)||m) approach will be malleable, for the reason I described in my previous comment. ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Answer (score 1):

If you follow [the advice to sign-then-encrypt](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/5466/13625) rather than encrypt-then-sign, you should probably use authenticated encryption. Otherwise you are going to be decrypting unauthenticated ciphertext, which with certain ciphers can be dangerous.

For example, with CBC-mode encryption, decrypting unauthenticated ciphertext can allow a [padding-oracle attack](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/padding-oracle). If you have a stream cipher, or other malleable cipher, an attacker could be able to change it to some earlier (signed) message, which may violate protocol assumptions like that different nonces mean different messages.

If you are going to sign the ciphertext, then that will indeed take care of authentication as Richie Frame [states](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/33009/13625).